# How to import an external js file in Quasar project

Tags: vue.js, quasar

In early javascript project, we have created a file named kresource.js, its code is below

```
//kresource file, contains some functions
var kresource = (function () {
    function kresource () {
    }
    kresource.getLang = function () {
      console.log('en')    //it's only a sample...
    }
    return kresource
})()
```

When in a html page, we can access the function by ***kresource.getLang()***, but in a Quasar vue page, how can I import this file, and access the function?

```
//index.vue file
import kresource from '../js/kresource.js'
```

**`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: _js_kresource_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.getLang is not a function"`**

Comment: The kresource file needs to export something in order for import to work.

Comment: Should I change the kresource file? I really want to keep the file unchanged, because some these files can be used into the early projects not only the quasar project. Thanks

Comment: Try `require('../js/kresource.js')`

Comment: After append the line: module.exports = kresource, it works, still need to be changed. I will make some change in the files. Thanks @danh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because you need to use that code as a module instead of relying on `var` being global.

You need to add an `export` to your file. At the end of the file you need to put:

```
export default kresource
```

And in the file where you plan to use it:

```
import kresource from 'path to the file'
```

Notes: You can read more about modules in JS so you can understand better what is hapening, and also instead of var use `const`, since that variable is never reasigned and it is better to maintain the global scope cleaner.

Comment: This is a very useful way to import external files. Thanks